# imagecreatefromstring too large, just want to rotate image

Tags: php, iphone, image, upload

So like many posts Ive read, when i upload a file to my website from my iphone, the image is rotated the wrong way. I understand why and I have a function that is reading the exif data to detect the orientation.

Ive also some code and a switch statement on here to rotate the image 90 degrees
the problem i have is that

```
 $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
```

returns that same old error that Allowed Memory size of x bytes exhausted

I dont have access to my php.ini to increase the max upload size
I cant do anything on this remote server with a .htaccess file either

Files uploaded from my iphone are all throwing this error as Im sure everyones iphone is as well

I can detect the image size using

```
  $info = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
```

How do I get around this problem as the switch statement is based on the $image var?
What am I to do with the file size (height and width) after i get it in the $info var?

Looking forward to replies
Thanks!

Comment: Does your "x" (displayed allowed memory size) apply to the size of the image? If it is much bigger, there could be an issue with the uploading.

Edit: My fault - the file size could be irrelevant - because if GD loads a jpeg it decompresses it and holds (so to say) a "width * height * color depth" bitmap.

Comment: it does match either way, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it really is the size, you can try to add

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');
```

to the top of the single relevant php script.

But there may be restrictions, too.

Comment: i ended up having to use ini_set('memory_limit', '80M'); before any call to imagecreatefromstring() and imagerotate() and that seemed to do the trick, good answer, but im not sure what i had to do is best practice. What may the restrictions be? - id like to upvote this answer but i guess i dont have the rep on here yet hehe

Comment: "But there may be restrictions, too." meant: I always had own webservers or webservers, where no restrictions were set to this option. But maybe the file-based "ini_set('memory..."-stuff can be limited or deactivated - but I don't know that.